# My imwrite function is not saving the frame of videocapture?

Tags: python-3.x

Whenever i press q it turns off th webcam but when i press s it doesn't save the frame.Why is that so
I have attached my code below

```
import cv2
frame=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
i=0;
while(True):
  ret,capture=frame.read()
  cv2.imshow("Webcam",capture)
  if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q'):
     break
  if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('s'):
     cv2.imwrite("Image "+str(i)+".jpg",capture)
     i+=1;
frame.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: When you press 'q', you break out of te while loop, the code to catch the 's' key never executes.

Comment: Try and increase the waitkey time to about 25, and soam `s` a few times, does that work? Or when you change the order, does that work?

Comment: Are you getting any error? If it is not a python-3 specific question, please consider to include the python tag.